# Symfony bundle - managing assets

Tags: symfony, webpack, bundle, assets

I am creating a symfony bundle.

I don't understand how to deal with assets in my bundle. I am used to Webpack Encore and I thought I could have my js/css with webpack encore as usual, generate production assets in the Resources/public directory as suggested by the Symfony Bundle good practises and it will work with the 'encore_entry_script_tags(nameoftheentry)'.

However, I am seeing that in fact, including assets as that in my twig templates in my bundle, it tries to find out assets inside the main application and not inside the bundle.

I don't know how to solve this.

Thank you in advance, have a great day.

Comment: Please share more details. Are you facing any error? Why not check how other bundles solve this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't really know other bundles, I am quite new to Symfony, so I can't really know where to find other bundles to compare.

Comment: Hi @AntoineC and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please provide from details (code). Because based on Symfony Documentation `encore_entry_script_tags` read from `entrypoints.json`